# passing command line arguments from xargs

Tags: bash, shell, sed, command-line-arguments, xargs

I have a shell script that does the following:

INPUT_DIR is a directory containing zip files.  The zip files look like lograw1.zip, lograw2.zip etc.

I have a program called prog.py that takes input as the zip file using an option -i and outputs a tsv file.  The tsv file corresponding to each zip file has a different name.

i.e, lograw1.zip gives an ouput of logprocessed1.tsv

I have a shell script with this for loop and it works perfectly.

```sh
for f in $INPUT_DIR/*.zip
  do
    filename=$(basename $f .zip)
    tsvfilename="$(basename "${f/raw/processed}" .zip).tsv"
    python /work/prog.py -i $f  $OUTPUT_DIR/$tsvfilename
  done
```

I want to make use of xargs in a bash script to read through the zips and submit to my prog doing similar renaming of files. How can I use xargs to send as an argument between a command?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not at *all* work perfectly if your files contain spaces in their names. Use more quotes!

Comment: ...to be more specific: `basename $f .zip` needs to be `basename "$f" .zip`. `python /work/prog.py -i $f $OUTPUT_DIR/$tsvfilename` needs to be `python /work/prog.py -i "$f" "$OUTPUT_DIR/$tsvfilename"`. `$INPUT_DIR/*.zip` needs to be `"$INPUT_DIR"/*.zip`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xargs works by taking a list of file names from standard input and running a command with all of the files it retrieves from standard input. If the length of standard input will overflow the command line buffer, `xargs` will divide up the list.

Let's do something simple:

```
ls | xargs /bin/echo
```

Let's say your directory looks like this:

- foo
- bar
- barfoo
- foobar
- barbar
- foofoo

The `ls` command will output:

```
foo bar barfoo foobar barbar foofoo
```

This will be passed to `/bin/echo` and the following will be executed:

```
/bin/echo foo bar barfoo foobar barbar foofoo
```

Now, let's say your input buffer is only 12 characters long, passing all of those files to `/bin/echo` will overrun your input buffer. `xargs` will take care of this for you by making sure it doesn't pass more than 10 characters of data to the `/bin/echo` command and will reexecute the `/bin/echo` command over and over until all files are passed to it:

```
/bin/echo foo bar
/bin/echo barfoo foobar
/bin/echo barber foofoo
```

You can test this by passing the `-s10` parameter to `xargs` which will limit the number of characters that `xargs` will take. You can also try the `-t` which will echo exactly what `xargs` is executing.

---

The reason for this tutorial is to understand that in order for `xargs` to work, each and every command your shell script must be able to use multiple files and this isn't the case. The `/work/prog.py` looks like it takes one file at a time, and so does the `basename` command.

You'll have to modify your script to take advantage of `xargs` in order for that to work. Probably by using a `for` loop to handle this.

Think about using `find` with your shell script which may do what you want:

```
find . -name "*.zip" -exec script.sh {} \;
```

There are issues with `xargs` (it doesn't handle file names with funky characters by default) and there is a question whether it is any faster. After all:

```
rm *
```

Still must remove the files passed to it one at a time, just like this little script does:

```
for file in *
do
    rm $file
done
```

In the old Unix days, starting a new process took a lot of overhead, so if you could run a command once instead of multiple, it could save you time. I don't know if this is now worth the trouble.

Comment: `xargs -n 1 command` would tell xargs to run `command` each time with only one argument.

Comment: The best explanation I've heard for xargs.

Comment: @David W. Thanks david, I can get it work using find, but cannot get the output file name right.  What I do is :find testzips/ -name *zip |sed "s| \(.*\)|/work/prog.py -i \1  outputs/\1.out|"|xargs python

Comment: @mofoe That's true, but there's not much benefit using `xargs` in that case.

Comment: Some points should probably be made about safe whitespace handling; the practices implicitly endorsed here are very much not safe for all possible filenames.

Comment: The `find -exec` command _executes_ a process and not a shell script. You need to pass it a executable or script that does what you want. Since you're running a Python script, why not modify the Python script do figure out the `tsvfilename` you want from the name of the file?

Comment: ...at least, make the `rm $file` be `rm "$file"` so a file named `"evil * evil"` doesn't expand into a list of every file in the current directory.

Comment: ...but then, the differences between xargs' default behavior, `xargs -d $'\n'`, and `xargs -0` really bear discussion for anything that's trying to be a guide on safe and correct usage.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, `xargs` has problems with whitespace handling, and I alluded to it when I mentioned about _funky file names_. I was mainly explaining how `xargs` works, and the problems with replacing the `for` loop with `xargs`.

Comment: @DAvid : Thanks. I think I will do that- modify my script to handle thefilename in python

Comment: xargs doesn't *have* to have problems with whitespace handling; it (or, at least, widely-deployed variants) _can_ be used safely, doing so just requires care.

Comment: @user1189851: Based on your `sed` expression, you could directly execute the command resulting from your substitution, with `e` command in `sed`. Just like this: `find testzips/ -name *zip | sed 's=\(.*\)=python work/prog.py -i \1 outputs/\1.out=e'` (Note the `e` at the end).

Comment: @Qeole `-name '*zip'`, you mean -- otherwise this'll break if there are any zip files in the current directory where it's run (by expanding the glob before `find` is started). Also, generating whitespace-separated word lists hardly a practice to encourage, since it breaks the minute one of your filenames contains whitespace.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Absolutely. Actually I copied/pasted that part from an upper comment, but I should have checked it of course. Thanks for the correction. So if I'm not mistaken, a correct line would be: `find testzips/ -name '*zip' | sed 's=\(.*\)=python work/prog.py -i "\1" "outputs/\1.out"=e'`

Comment: I wouldn't really call that correct either -- think of filenames containing literal quotation marks. The entire approach is somewhat error-prone.

Comment: ...the real Right Thing is to use `xargs -0` with a NUL-delimited string. To be sure, `sed` can't be used to create those strings easily, but a shell loop (doing `read` on one side and `printf '%s\0' ...` on the other) can. Of course, you don't need the `read` end if you're just iterating over glob results, either.